# Creating columns with data.table - difference in `:=` and := syntax

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I want to understand the underlying difference between `:=` syntax and := syntax in data.table for R. I use this function to programatically generate column names.

I am trying to figure out why the last line of code will not work:

```
#Make test data
test <- data.table()
test[, a := 1:5]
test[, b := 6:10]

#Create c column in various ways
test[, c := a+b] #works
test[, `:=`(c = a+b)] #works
test[, paste0("c") := a + b] #works
test[, `:=`(paste0("c") = a + b)] #does not work
```

This example is very simple. I use this type of paste0 to programatically generate column names. I know that `test[, paste0("c") := a+b]` works. However, I want to understand why the same thing, but in `:=` syntax will not. This is odd to me. Also, making this work, would make my code cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take addition for example. If you do

```
3 + 2
```

that's the same as

```
`+`(3, 2)
```

When you call an "infix" function like `+`, it's the same as calling the function with two parameters, the left hand side and the right hand side. So when you use the function

```
a := b
```

that's the same as

```
`:=`(a, b)
```

There are no named arguments in there. Note there is no `=` in there.

The main reason people use `:=` is that in the R language syntax, `=` cannot include an expression on the left side when defining function arguments (named parameters). It only allows character values or symbols for the name of a parameter. The expression

```
foo(paste0("c") = a + b)
```

just cannot be understood by the R parser. This isn't specific to data.table at all. Even if you just run

```
quote(foo(paste0("c") = a + b))
```

you get the error

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "quote(foo(paste0("c") ="
```

Your last line is just invalid R syntax.

More uses are described on the `help(":=")` page, and it does show examples using the "functional form" where you can have named parameters, but those parameter names need to follow the R syntax just described. So if you want dynamic names, don't use the function form, use the "LHS := RHS" form.